# How to create Multiple Apk and ipa for multiple clients in same project and codebase by changing only app name and Logo?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

i want to create multiple builds for multiple clients by changing app logo and name.and i am using push notification of firebase so i dont now that how to do it using Google-services.json.

Comment: Consider using product flavours and for React Native use this Library https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config

Comment: can you explain me with demo or step by step

Comment: Try integrating the library with your React Native project,  Documentation is available in the library itself for you to integrate.

Comment: ok I have Created productFlavours.but when i create the Signed apk then axios stop working for webservieces and gives me network error. any solutions? and also images not appearing in application.

Comment: Can you add some steps and code on how did you generate an signed APK? Did you integrate React Native Config?

Comment: yes i use react native config for default api  of local and live server url. but it works in debug mode but when i release it. it does not work in productFlavor

Comment: Http request and webservices is not working when i generate signed apk of product flavor. please i need solution.

Comment: Can you add some steps and code on how did you generate an signed APK?

Comment: flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors{
        xxxxxx{
            dimension "default"
            applicationId "com.xxxxxxxx.crm"
            resValue "string", "override_name", "Mother Teresa Memorial School"
            versionName "2.0"
            versionCode 12
            resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.xxxxxx.xxxx"
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    appIcon: "@mipmap/ic_motherteresa"
            ]
            buildConfigField("string","HOST","http://xxxxxxxx.com:9100")
        }
    }

Comment: Did i need to create Different keystore files(.jks) for each build productFlavor?

Comment: Update the code in the question section https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80538/how-to-ask-questions-on-stack-overflow